# Impersonation denied from trustworthy database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using EXECUTE AS to allow a least-privilege user to run some SQL stored procedures as a sysadmin. I know that I need TRUSTWORTHY=ON on the source database (the one running the stored procedures) in order to impersonate the sysadmin on other databases on my server. However, even with impersonation granted and TRUSTWORTHY=ON, I still get the following error when trying to touch other databases as the impersonated user:

```
The server principal [least_privileged user] is not able to access the database XXX under the     current security context.
```

(And yes, I know that module signing is the more secure option. I'm not looking to go that route.)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The stored procedure EXECUTE AS clause allows you to impersonate a database user, not a login.  You can add the user to the other database to prevent the error.  Exactly what are you doing that requires sysadmin role membership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `execute as owner`.
- Make sure the procedure is in the `dbo` schema.
- Make sure the database owner has sysadmin rights on the instance. I
  have noticed that SQL logins work better for this purpose than ones
  from Windows.
- Check `trustworthy=on` for the database.

This way, you don't need additional impersonation grants, but it is a **way** less secure solution. It will work, though.